# How to remove warning message in ReactMeteorData?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm doing a project on Meteor and I have a warning message in console.

`Warning: MeteorDataContainer: React.createClass is deprecated and will be removed in version 16. Use plain JavaScript classes instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement.`

But in the code I use only plain JavaScript classes to create React components (abridged version).

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.user}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('Meteor.users.public');

  return {
    user: Meteor.user()
  };
}, Header);
```

How can I fix this warning? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be getting addressed by MDG right now:

https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/pull/217